# C++ Delete all lines in a .txt file up until a certain keyword is reached

Tags: c++, text

I am fairly new to C++, and I'm trying write a code to run some analysis on large data files.  I've managed to write code that produces a text file where only one word/number is displayed per line (there are millions of lines).  However, the first ~3000 or so lines contain useless stuff not needed for my analysis.

The only problem is, the actual data starts at a different line number depending on the input file.

Is there any way to write a quick code which would search the text document and remove all lines up until the point the keyword `"<event>"` is found?

Update: 
I got it to work! May be a little more complicated than what was suggested but it still works.

Thanks for the help!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        int counter = 0;

    ifstream FileSearch("OutputVector.txt"); // search OutputVector input file.

    while(!FileSearch.eof())
    {
        counter++;
        string temp;
        FileSearch >> temp;

        if(temp == "<event>")
        {
            break; //While loop adding +1 to counter each time <event> is not found.
        }
    }



    std::ofstream outFile("./final.txt"); //Create output file "final.txt."
    std::string line;

 std::ifstream inFile("OutputVector.txt"); //open input file OutputVector again.

 int count = 0;

 while(getline(inFile, line)){

     if(count > counter-2){
        outFile << line << std::endl;
     }
     count++; //while loop counts from counter-2 until the end and writes them to the new file.
 }
 outFile.close();
 inFile.close(); //close the files.
 remove("OutputVector.txt"); //Delete uneeded OutputVector File.
}
```

Comment: Read the source file and write desired parts to another file.

Comment: Do you want to actually modify the input file or just skip the for X lines?

Comment: I've tried to use standard keyword finding techniques to actually find the specific line, but none of them seem to actually give a line number when found.

Comment: Also, I'm hoping to modify the input file.

Comment: You should not be modifying input file just in case Murphy strikes. Standard technique is to make a new file, copy stuff there, close it, and then move it over the old file. But it should be faster just to skip lines you don't want.

Comment: When analyzing large files it can often be helpful to create a metadata index about the files. This way you don't need to modify the original file and you save the extracted information for later use. In your case you could scan the file to find the starting point of the real data and write that starting point into another file. Then you'd know where to move to right away, without deleting the first part of the file.

Comment: @user3427419: To be extra safe against Murphy write the new file, call fsync(), *check the return value for errors*, and *then* close the file.

Comment: @Zack: please remove your answer from your post, as it goes against Stack Overflow's intentions as a "Question and Answer" site. If you want, you can *submit* it as a proper answer.

Comment: I'd prefer it if he didn't submit it as an answer. It's a very poor solution to the problem and leaving it here propagates bad thinking about how to use file streams.

Comment: @user4581301: that may well be true, but *bad* answers are still allowed. (And you are free to downvote them ;) and suggest improvements.) I could copy this answer out of the post and submit it as [Community wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), but like you I'm not so sure it's worth the trouble. Anyway, if OP doesn't change this post, I'm going to roll it back.

Answer (score 2):

Basic skeleton:

```
std::ifstream stream("file name goes here")
std::string line;
// optional: define line number here
while (std::getline (stream, line))
{
    // optional: increment line number here
    if (line.find("<event>") != line.npos)
    {  // Deity of choice help you if <event> naturally occurs in junk lines. 
       // Extra smarts may be required here.
        doStuffWithRestOfFile(stream);
        break;
    } 
}
```

Not enough information on how you wish to modify the source file to answer that sub-question. Once you get the reader going, ask a new question if you haven't figured it out.

Edit: Short version

```
std::ifstream stream("file name goes here")
std::string line;
// optional: define line number here
while (std::getline (stream, line) && (line.find("<event>") == line.npos))
{
    // optional: increment line number here
}
doStuffWithRestOfFile(stream);
```

Comment: I don't like this pattern. IMO, it would be better to call `doStuffWithRestOfFile` outside of the file loop.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk Personal preference or are their tactical/readability reasons? I went with this because I thought the flow was more obvious than my personal preference of `while (std::getline (stream, line) && line.find("<event>") == line.npos)` an empty loop and then `doStuffWithRestOfFile`

Comment: The purpose of the while loop is to bring the stream state to the point you want it. When the event occurs, the purpose of the while loop is done. Conceptually I see it like this: step 1: skip garbage, step 2: process good stuff. The pattern you're using makes it seem like step 2 is a part of step 1. IMO, your edit is much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the file with the new version ( without the beginning ) you can either read all the file to memory and override it, or write to a second file while reading the first one, and move/rename it after

to read all line until you find `<event>` :

```
std::ifstream input_file( filePath );
std::string line;
int current_line = 0;

do
{
   std::getline( input_file, line );
   ++current_line;
}
while( line.find("<event>") == line.npos );
// use input_line to process the rest of the file
```

Keep in mind that if `"<event>"` is a the first line, then after the `do while`, `current_line` will contain 1, not 0

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code to use a `do while` instead

Comment: should be `while (line.find("<event>") == line.npos)`

Comment: Fails to test if getline succeeded. Will operate on at least one invalid line at end of file.

Comment: I did suppose that there was eventually a `"<event>"`

Comment: And if there isn't or there is a file error, you have the dreaded undefined behaviour, probably an infinite loop as the last successfully read value of  line gets continually retested.